# One of my three monitors refuses to go into power saving mode after recent Windows update

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, updates, powersave

Very weird situation. I have this Windows 8.1 desktop with 3 monitors. The power setting in CP is to show password protected screensaver after 5 minutes of inactivity, and then turn all of them off after 30 minutes. It used to work great until...

I installed a bunch of Windows updates yesterday. And now only two of the screens go into power saving mode. I just noticed it when I walked into the room with no light and saw this bluish glow coming off of one screen.

I tried to tweak display settings in CP, reboot, but it didn't help.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Uninstall each update one by one, to see, if you can get it to behave correctly without the updates being installed

Comment: @Ramhound: I remember there was an option update dealing with Acer or something like that, which I should've never installed. But where do I find it? It's not on the list of installed updates.

Comment: You have to provide more precise information.